# How to set correctly jQuery progressbar height?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to set the jQuery UI progressbar height, using jQuery UI 1.10.3

Although the div seems to be correctly sized, the inside progress obviously not, the right bottom seems to be cut.

I am using the following code:

```
$div = $("#mydiv");
$div.progressbar({
    value: percent
});
$div.height(20);
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: We need your HTML and CSS as well. Modifying the default progress bar's height works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I've tried to CSS the div's height to 20px, which gives _exaclty_ the same result. (not surprisingly) The html is <div id='mydiv'></div>

Comment: Right, that's not what I'm saying. Your progress bar is different from the default [jQuery UI Progress Bar](https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) which does work when you modify the div's height. Therefore we need to know what's different about yours.

Comment: It looks like you want to select the `<div>` by its ID: `$("#mydiv")`. [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xw4b6hx9/).

Comment: @showdev: thx that was only in the SO code exhibit. now fixed

Comment: OK, understand, probably interfers with jqgrid styles